# tikz does not plot correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

@Jake: this is the whole document

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgflibrary{arrows}
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{Tikz-exp}


    \parindent=0pt

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{x={(.965cm,-.258cm)}, y={(.7cm,.7cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},
    sezioni/.style={draw=#1!60, thin, fill=#1!30, fill opacity=0.3},
    scale=1.75
    }
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0) node [left] {$O$};
    \draw[gray,->] (-2,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node [right, black] {$x$};
    \draw[gray, ->] (0,-2,0) -- (0,2,0) node [right, black] {$y$};
    \draw[gray, ->] (O) -- (0,0,3) node [left, black] {$z$};

    %=====% sezioni %=====%
    \foreach \x in {-1,-.85,...,1}
        \draw[sezioni=teal] (\x,{sqrt(1-(\x)^2)},0)--(\x,0,{sqrt(4*(1-(\x)^2))})--(\x,{-sqrt(1-(\x)^2)},0)--(\x,{sqrt(1-(\x)^2)},0);
    %=====================%

    \draw[blue] (O) circle (1);
    \draw[red, domain=-1:1, samples=500] plot (\x,0,{sqrt(4*(1-(\x)^2))});
    \end{tikzpicture}



    \end{document}
```

The red map in x=1 should produce the value zero, but it is positive.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, welcome to the site! This is a known bug that's been fixed in the development version of PGF. There's a bugfix at the linked question.

Comment: A fine solution is to install gnuplot : `\draw plot[id=f,domain=-1:1] function{sqrt(4*(1-x**2))}; `

Comment: @Lorenzo: Actually, I take that back, the fix at the linked question works for `2^\x`, but not for `\x^2`. You'll need to say `(\x)^2` to get the correct plot.

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, in x=1 it doesn't produce z=0...

Comment: @Lorenzo: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What does it produce instead? Could you edit your question to include a screenshot of your output, and turn the code snippet into a complete minimal compilable document (starting from `\documentclass`)?

Comment: @Jake: the code above should be compilable with every preamble (with tikz and color packages, of course). This is not an error, just an output bug. (In addition, actually I can't post screenshot because my reputation is 5...)

Comment: @Lorenzo: It may be compilable with every preamble, but it's generally preferred if full example documents are posted so it's easier to try the code out, and to rule out the possibility of any "side-effects" of packages that may be loaded. Note that you don't need to load `color` if you're loading `tikz`. If you have less than 10 rep, you can insert the picture and then remove the `!` from the code, someone else will then edit the question to insert it back in.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a numerical inaccuracy when determining where to sample the function. The following code makes sure that the upper bound of the `domain` is always sampled:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@plot@samples@recalc#1:#2\relax{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}%
  \let\tikz@temp@start=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \let\tikz@temp@end=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{\tikz@temp@start+(\tikz@temp@end-\tikz@temp@start)/(\tikz@plot@samples-1)}%
  \edef\tikz@plot@samplesat{\tikz@temp@start,\pgfmathresult,...,\tikz@temp@end,\tikz@temp@end}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,0,0) -- (2,0,0);

    \draw[red, domain=-1:1, samples=50] plot (\x,{sqrt(4*(1-(\x)^2))});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```